# Connection issues

Tags: 8, database, acquia-dev-desktop

New to Drupal 8 and tripped up on this one. It seems something wrong with database but if anyone has tips please let me know!
Here is my code:
[image]

and here is error:
[image]

And my drupal site isn't working at all:
[image]

Not really even sure where to start looking. Also, using Acquia DevDesktop if that helps at all. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you don't have a port configured. I'm not sure if drupal will use 3306 if a port isn't specified.

Comment: It's running on local site: http://drupal8theming.dd:8083/ which would be port 8803 correct? And I tried that but no luck

Comment: It needs to be the port that the database is running on. 3306 is default. I haven't used Acquia devdesktop, but it looks like it has a ports tab that will tell you what port your database is running on. Or, if you can run commands in mysql, `mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';` will tell you the port.

Comment: Another possibility is that your code isn't being reached. It needs to be in sites/default/files/settings.php, or settings.php needs to be loading the file the code is in. `if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
}`

Comment: The port isn't the issue. My code is in sites/default and has this code:
```// Please don't edit anything between <DDSETTINGS> tags.
// This section is autogenerated by Acquia Dev Desktop.
if (isset($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR']) && file_exists($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] . '/loc_drupal8theming_dd.inc')) {
  require $_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] . '/loc_drupal8theming_dd.inc';
}
```

Comment: You are overriding the database settings that are created automatically by Acquia DevDesktop. Why? Have you tested that your DB configuration even works - without Drupal? And I think the standard DB port for Acquia DevDesktop 33066

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Acquia DevDesktop** create it's configuration inside *USER_DIR/.acquia/DevDesktop/DrupalSettings/* folder in file called `loc_drupal8theming_dd.inc` in your case.
So no need to add another Database configuration.
Just remove the last part 
`$databases['default']['default'] = [ ] ...`

Comment: I found that file but it says "PLEASE DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, IT IS AUTOGENERATED BY ACQUIA DEV DESKTOP". So if I remove the Database configuration I have, I get the error:
```RuntimeException: Missing $settings['hash_salt']
 ```
Then if I had the $settings["hash_salt"] I get the error: 
```Drupal\Core\Database\ConnectionNotDefinedException: The specified database connection is not defined: default in /Users/joe/Sites/devdesktop/drupal8theming/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php:361
```

Comment: this is duo to another thing add to your setting.php something like  `$settings['hash_salt'] = "_pFAkhHKGG24fM74jRI2rEhMrjTFOfnAOLE4hZAoDx9TYZmr2lNhMsjf-gJttupyefmC3jtRhQ"`

Comment: I can at least run "drush cr" in terminal and it doesn't give any errors. However, the same error I posted in my initial question on the actual Drupal page still shows up so I can't navigate my site at all. Any tips for next debugging steps? It's telling me the server responded with a status of 500.

Comment: What I ended up doing was copying the database configuration in my ```loc_drupal8theming_dd.inc```file and pasting it into my ```settings.php``` file inside my Drupal site codebase. That at least took care of the terminal errors I was getting but still no luck on the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, updating Drupal ended up solving my issue: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-drush.
Even though there were no updates to be made, I guess something in that process (I think dropping then updating my database) resolved my site issues. Thanks to everyone though because they helped solve my first command line error.